# Finding intersection of a sphere and a plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Suppose I have the sphere  $\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4  $ and the plane $\  x-y\sqrt{3} =0. $

How do I find the intersection curve and write it in polar terms?

In polar coordinates the sphere is just $\ r = 2 $

substituting $\ x = \sqrt3  y $ in ball equation:

$$ \ (\sqrt3 y)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 \\ 3r^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + r^2 \sin^2\theta \sin^2 \phi + r^2 \cos^2\phi =4 \\ r^2 \sin^2\phi \cdot 3 + r^2\cos^2\phi = 4 \\ r^2(3\sin^2\phi+\cos^2\phi) = 4$$

Comment: Substitute $x=y\sqrt3$ in the ball expression? Then polarize after?

Comment: Thank you, how do I get rid of the 3 in my equation??

Comment: You don't remove the 3?

Comment: I’m not sure I can see how?

Comment: What you have right now is fine.

Comment: Thanks again! yet, I don't understand, what are the polar coordinates for the curve I was looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find orthogonal vectors each of length (radius) $2$ in the plane given:

$(1, \sqrt{3},0)$ and $(0,0,2)$

Now create a trigonometric (polar) sum of these vectors:

$$\cos \theta (1, \sqrt{3}, 0) + \sin \theta (0,0,2) = (\cos \theta, \sqrt{3} \cos \theta, 2 \sin \theta)$$

[image]

In traditional polar coordinates:

$$(r, \theta, \phi) \to (2, 60^\circ, \phi)\ {\rm for}\ 0 < \phi < 2 \pi $$

Comment: This is really good visual plot. May I ask what did you use to make it?

Comment: *Mathematica*..